# Capistrano 3 deployment is broken

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

my capistrano3 deployment is broken. I really don't know why, it was like yesterday it works and today it doesn't. Please have a look at the error it gives me:

```
cap aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /tmp/PROJECT-0d9226685f71.tar.gz
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp/upload.rb:117:in `stat'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp/upload.rb:117:in `set_current'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp/upload.rb:24:in `upload_start_state'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:369:in `block (3 levels) in start_command'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:324:in `call'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:324:in `process'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:223:in `block in preprocess'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:223:in `each'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:223:in `preprocess'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:206:in `process'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `block in loop'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:284:in `upload!'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:34:in `block in upload!'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:141:in `with_ssh'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:33:in `upload!'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/capistrano-scm-gitcopy-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/gitcopy.rake:79:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:64:in `within'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/capistrano-scm-gitcopy-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/gitcopy.rake:77:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:15:in `instance_exec'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:15:in `run'
/Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@SERVER/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => gitcopy:create_release
The deploy has failed with an error: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - /tmp/PROJECT-0d9226685f71.tar.gz
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

I don't know what it is. Maybe some capistrano bug or a bug in my configs? Let me know if you need more informations

Answer (score 1):

Answer is following:

https://github.com/xuwupeng2000/capsitrano-scm-gitcopy#installation

> Finally, DO NOT ADD require 'capistrano/gitcopy' to Capfile because capistrano/setup already loads the scm module with the :scm value you specified.